# R - Shiny: start server.R without using R studio

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shiny-server

I am using R without RStudio, trying to start the R shiny server inside R. Here is what I have when I am in R.

```
> dir()
 [1] "app.R"                   "data.R"                           
 [3] "server.R"                "server.Rout"            
 [5] "testData.R"              "ui.R"    

> source(server.R)
Error in source(server.R) : object 'server.R' not found
```

How do I properly run server.R from here? Thanks!

Comment: `source("app.R")`

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the regular `runApp()` doesn't work? This info is available [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/running.html), and I had no problem when I tried it with the example app... (Also, why do you have both app.R AND server.R and ui.R? - you should have one or the other...)